# Formating View in maatwebsite Excel Export

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I am new to maatwebsite Excel Export i am using view Excel Export in laravel and would like to know how one can specify the cell number where the data should go like a h1 tag like below snippet

```html
<h5>PURCHASE ORDER</h5>



<hr>
<div class="container-flow">
<table id="table" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm text-center">
<thead>
<tr>
<th  scope="col">No.</th>
<th  scope="col">Product_Code</th>
<th  scope="col"> Item_Description </th>
<th scope="col">Qty</th>
<th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
<th scope="col" >Value</th>
<th scope="col">Stock Less 90 Days</th>
<th scope="col">Stock More 90 Days</th>
```

when i export i get this
[image]

i would like to specify the cell where that  tag should go like say cell B3 instead of current position cell A1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put some empty tags / cells before.
Try

```
   <table>
     <tr></tr>
     <tr></tr>
     <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td><h5>PURCHASE ORDER</h5></td>
    </tr>
   </table>

<hr>
<div class="container-flow">
<table id="table" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm text-center">
<thead>
<tr>
<th  scope="col">No.</th>
<th  scope="col">Product_Code</th>
<th  scope="col"> Item_Description </th>
<th scope="col">Qty</th>
<th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
<th scope="col" >Value</th>
<th scope="col">Stock Less 90 Days</th>
<th scope="col">Stock More 90 Days</th>
```

Comment: This just pushed the h5 two cell down vertically my idea is to move both vertically and horizontally

Comment: you could create another table at the top and fill the cells empty to move the tag around, see my updated answer

Comment: thanks thats what i wanted

Comment: you may accept my answer if you succeeded to solve your issue